# How to implement a Guid generator with insertBuilder on Nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I'd like to do a bulk insert with nhibernate using the insertBuilder.
But I want each row to have a unique Guid.

```
var mailIds = batch.Select(x => x.Id);
var guidGen = new GuidGenerator();

  Dao.Evaluate(s => s.Query<Mail>()
      .Where(es => mailIds.Contains(es.Id))
      .InsertBuilder()
      .Into<Attachment>()
      .Value<Guid>(c => c.Id, guidGen.Generate(s.GetSessionImplementation(), c))//The property expression must refer to a property of c(Attachment)
      .Value(c => c.Filename, fileName)
      .Value(c => c.Type.Id, attachmentType.Id)
      .Value(c => c.Media.Id, media.Id)
      .Value(c => c.LastChangedBy, IdentityHelper.CurrentUserName)
      .Value(c => c.LastChangedOn, DateTime.Now)
      .Value(c => c.CreatedBy, IdentityHelper.CurrentUserName)
      .Value(c => c.CreatedOn, DateTime.Now)
      .Insert());
```

I've tried using the guidGenerator, but that doesn't work.

I've tried a list and do a where-select, but that can't be converted to sql.

So how do I get this to work?
Thanks already

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a `List` of guids and then use them as the value for the Id column in the insert builder.

```
var guIds = Enumerable.Range(0, mailIds.Count())
                         .Select(_ => Guid.NewGuid())
                         .ToList();
```

and in the builder instead of

```
.Value<Guid>(c => c.Id, guidGen.Generate(s.GetSessionImplementation(), c))//The property expression must refer to a property of c(Attachment)
```

Add the following

```
.Value<Guid>(c => c.Id, () => guIds[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`InsertBuilder()` generates single insert SQL statement. So the real question here is how to generate new GUID for each row on DB side.

If you are using NHibernate v5.3+ you can try disabling legacy LINQ evaluation by setting session factory `linqtohql.legacy_preevaluation` setting to `false` (related [issue](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/959)):

```xml
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="linqtohql.legacy_preevaluation">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Or via code:

```
//Somewhere before session factory is created:
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration configuration = ...
configuration.SetProperty(Environment.LinqToHqlLegacyPreEvaluation, "false");
```

And then simply use `Guid.NewGuid()` in your LINQ insert query:

```
 .Value(c => c.Id, Guid.NewGuid());
```

`Guid.NewGuid()` should be transformed to proper SQL generating new GUID for your dialect.

NOTE: Be aware that this setting will make all supported by DB methods to be converted to SQL (so `DateTime.Now` call in LINQ will be converted to `GETDATE()` and so on). But if you need client-side calculation you need to move such calls to variables. Something like:

```
var curDate = DateTime.Now;
...
insertBuilder.Value(c => c.CreatedOn, curDate)
...
```